# Is the Staff of Herding successfully shareable between all your characters?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does one need to farm up the mats on each character so that multiple staves can be created, or is one staff (per difficulty, etc.) enough, since it can be used by any character you have?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Staff of Herding is tied to your Account, not your Characters.

Which means you can pretty much use it for any character you have in your Account as long as you have it in your inventory when you visit the Spirit of the Cow King.

Also, i'm pretty sure one Staff can open all the Whimsyshires below the current Mode Level, which is to say a Nightmarish Staff of Herding can also open a Whimsyshire on Normal. Like backwards compatibility.

Comment: Can't remember if thanking you is against the rules, but thank you. I've also come to the understanding that if you have a friend who is always with you in-game, he doesn't need to make one at all, as yours will get him in, if he's in your game. This will significantly cut down on farming-time-spent in this house!

Comment: @JetSetRadioFuture: You just need someone to open the level; should be ok even if they leave the game once the portal is opened.

Comment: @JetSet Welcome to the site!  The best way to thank people for a correct answer on this site is to click the checkmark to "accept" the answer, which gives the answerer a reputation bonus for helping you.  You can also click the up arrow for good measure (or to "thank" good answers on questions you didn't write).

Comment: Ah, just now figured out how!

Comment: Cheers. Hope you enjoy your stay here at Gaming SE!